# No longer want mypackage.myapp (pid 7433): hidden #16 error on using LoginButton?

Tags: android, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

I've created a sample project which loads a fragment containing LoginButton widget. It works absolutely fine, returning me GraphUser object. Then I embedded this code into my active project. Initially, it returned me the GraphUser object.

However, few days later when I checked the code again it gives me this error after submitting the facebook user credentials:

`I/ActivityManager(215): No longer want com.org.app (pid 7433): hidden #16`
`I/WindowManager(215): WIN DEATH: Window{40f8d808 com.org.app/com.facebook.LoginActivity paused=false}`

Also, my activity is destroyed.

**Please note**, the same fragment with the LoginButton runs absolutely fine in a different project.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved. Created a new android project. Shifted all my files to it. The issue occurred, I think, due to git merge.